# Multiple COUNTs on complex subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt, count

I have a complex SQL query with subqueries that cumulates sums to use in XSLT. The DB essentially gives back the XML rows and the XSL works with them. Now the whole thing works just fine, but sadly it appears that there is a lot of repetition in the query that I feel is not necessary.

Essentially I have the same COUNT query three times in subqueries, but there are different WHERE statements. One query gets all from a table, one gets a subsection and one gets a different subsection. The queries are entirely the same, apart from two added conditions.

I've seen some solutions using SUM, but since the query is a subquery and contains joins those don't really work.

The tables that I'm selecting and joining from are fairly large. One of the queries computes fairly quickly, but having multiple of the same selects drastically increases load time.

Is there a way to combine these subqueries so that the large select only happens once instead of 3 times?

```
SELECT  Matrix.FT_CODE as Code

    ,   (   SELECT  COUNT(Partner.TOPIC_ID)
            FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
            INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID       
            WHERE   Matrix.FT_CODE=Partner.TOPIC_ID and AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()
            )   AS APTotal

    ,   (   SELECT  COUNT(Partner.TOPIC_ID)
            FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
            INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID
            WHERE   (Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(Partner.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'00.00.00.00'  AND substring(Partner.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'99.99.99.99' ) and AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()
            )   AS APSum2

    ,   (   SELECT  COUNT(Partner.TOPIC_ID)
            FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
            INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID
            WHERE   (Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(Partner.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'00.00.00'  AND substring(Partner.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'99.99.99' ) and AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()
            )   AS APSum3

FROM        BTA_FINAL AS Matrix         
WHERE       Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN '1.00.00.00.00.00' AND '1.99.99.99.99.99'
FOR         XML AUTO
```

This query is written in an XML file and renderes with XLS, so there is little data computing I can do after the DB is done.

An example result might look like this:

```
<Matrix Code="1.09.17.06.04.00" APTotal="11" APSum2="564" APSum3="75" />
```

I loop over a few hundred of these to generate my markup. The numbers are necessary for conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE would be the right approach indeed when you have repetitive queries. I came up with 2 :

```
WITH PartnerCTE AS
(
SELECT  Partner.TOPIC_ID, Matrix.FT_CODE
        FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert 
        ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
        INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID  
    WHERE AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()   
)
SELECT  Matrix.FT_CODE as Code

,   (   SELECT  COUNT(TOPIC_ID)
        FROM PartnerCTE 
        WHERE   Matrix.FT_CODE=Partner.TOPIC_ID
        )   AS APTotal

,   (   SELECT  COUNT(TOPIC_ID)
        FROM PartnerCTE 
        WHERE   (Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'00.00.00.00'  AND substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'99.99.99.99' )
        )   AS APSum2

,   (   SELECT  COUNT(TOPIC_ID)
        FROM PartnerCTE 
        WHERE   (Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'00.00.00'  AND substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'99.99.99' )
        )   AS APSum3

 FROM        BTA_FINAL AS Matrix         
 WHERE       Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN '1.00.00.00.00.00' AND '1.99.99.99.99.99'
 FOR         XML AUTO
```

and the second one

```
WITH PartnerCTE AS
  (
    SELECT  Partner.TOPIC_ID, Matrix.FT_CODE
        FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
        INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID  
    WHERE AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()   
   )

 SELECT  

    Matrix.FT_CODE as Code,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE=PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    )END APTotal,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'00.00.00.00'  AND substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,5)+'99.99.99.99' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    )END APSum2,
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'00.00.00'  AND substring(PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID,1,8)+'99.99.99' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    )END APSum3,

        FROM  PartnerCTE,  BTA_FINAL AS Matrix
        GROUP BY Matrix.FT_CODE
```

Another try, taking away some repeated string processing:

```
WITH PartnerCTE AS
(
SELECT  
    Partner.TOPIC_ID,
    LEFT(Partner.TOPIC_ID,5) TOPIC_ID5,
    LEFT(Partner.TOPIC_ID,8) TOPIC_ID8,
    FROM    EXP_EXPERTISE_TOPIC AS Partner INNER JOIN KNW_AP AS Expert ON Partner.EXPERTISE_ID = Expert.AP_ID 
    INNER JOIN AK_PERS AS Person ON Expert.AP_AK_PE_ID = Person.PE_ID  
WHERE AP_DATE_EXPIRED > getdate()   
)

SELECT  

Matrix.FT_CODE as Code,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE=PartnerCTE.TOPIC_ID THEN 1
    ELSE 0
)END APTotal,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN TOPIC_ID5+'00.00.00.00'  AND TOPIC_ID5+'99.99.99.99' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
)END APSum2,
    SUM(CASE
    WHEN Matrix.FT_CODE BETWEEN TOPIC_ID8+'00.00.00'  AND TOPIC_ID8+'99.99.99' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
)END APSum3,

    FROM  PartnerCTE,  BTA_FINAL AS Matrix
    GROUP BY Matrix.FT_CODE
```

Comment: This looks nicer and works (after some tweaking), but sadly it does not offer any performance improvement.

Comment: @aFreshMelon - which one did you try? first of second?

Comment: I guess some indexes on FT_CODE and TOPIC_ID would help

Comment: @aFreshMelon, I added the 3rd query, taking away some of the repetition of the strings processing

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server, you can use CTE(common table expressions) instead of subqueries.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

You can create a CTE and then apply where clauses. This will result in much shorter and cleaner code.